# How to change the nested array object to object depending on type in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to change nested array object to object depending on key in javascript

I have objects `obj1` and `obj2`, depending on key `item` type change the object.

```
function changeObj(obj){
  let result =  obj.reduce(function (acc, item) {
      if(item.items.trim() !== "" && item.key.trim() !== ""){
        acc[item.key] = item.items
        return acc
      }
        return acc
    }, {});
  return result;
}
let result = this.changeObj(obj2)
var obj1 = [
 { id:0, items:["SG","AU"], count: 2, key:"countries"},
 { id:1, items:["finance"], count: 3 key:"info"} 
]

var obj2 = [
  { id:0, items: "SG", key: "country"},
  { id:1, items: "details", key: "info"}
]

Expected Output:

// if items key is array
{
  fields: {
    countries: ["SG","AU",2],
    info: ["finance",3]
  }
}

//if items key is string

{
  fields: {
    country: "SG",
    info: "details"
  }
}
```

Comment: So where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for reply, if the item key is array, not workin

Comment: So you need another conditional for `if(Array.isArray(item.items))` then

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason your code is not running is because the wrong format of your objects (1 and 2). Your code is okay except the condition because `trim()` only works on string type so it errors on array. Try this code snippet

```js
function changeObj(obj){
  let result =  obj.reduce(function (acc, item) {
      acc[item.key] = item.items;
      return acc;
    }, {});
  return result;
}

var obj1 = [
 { id:0, items:["SG","AU"], count: 2, key:"countries"},
 { id:1, items:["finance"], count: 3, key:"info"} 
]

var obj2 = [
  { id:0, items: "SG", key: "country"},
  { id:1, items: "details", key: "info"}
]

console.log(changeObj(obj1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const changeObj = obj =>
  obj.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (Array.isArray(item.items)) {
      acc[item.key] = [...item.items, item.count];
    } else {
      acc[item.key] = item.items;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});

var obj1 = [
  { id: 0, items: ['SG', 'AU'], count: 2, key: 'countries' },
  { id: 1, items: ['finance'], count: 3, key: 'info' }
];

var obj2 = [
  { id: 0, items: 'SG', key: 'country' },
  { id: 1, items: 'details', key: 'info' }
];

console.log(changeObj(obj1));
console.log(changeObj(obj2));
```

or cleaned up even more

```js
const changeObj = obj =>
  obj.reduce((acc, { items, key, count }) => {
    Array.isArray(items) ? (acc[key] = [...items, count]) : (acc[key] = items);

    return acc;
  }, {});

var obj1 = [
  { id: 0, items: ['SG', 'AU'], count: 2, key: 'countries' },
  { id: 1, items: ['finance'], count: 3, key: 'info' }
];

var obj2 = [
  { id: 0, items: 'SG', key: 'country' },
  { id: 1, items: 'details', key: 'info' }
];

console.log(changeObj(obj1));
console.log(changeObj(obj2));
```